# Nested loops with Selenium to list several tables

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, nested-loops

I am trying to list all rows from all tables (all with the same format) of a website. I have been able to extract data from one table but I don't know how to built the lop for getting all data. This is the code I am using:

```
Sub GetResults()
Dim wd As New WebDriver
Dim table As WebElement
Dim actualRowNumber As Long

wd.Start "chrome"
wd.Get "https://www.worldathletics.org/competition/calendar-results/results/7147613?day=2"

For Each table In wd.FindElementsByCss("[role=table]")
    RowNum = table.FindElementsByTag("tr").Count
    ColNum = table.FindElementsByTag("td").Count
    
    For i = 1 To RowNum
        actualRowNumber = actualRowNumber + i
        
        For j = 1 To ColNum
            Range("a2").Offset(i - 1, j - 1) = table.FindElementsByTag("tr")(i).FindElementsByTag("td")(j).Text
        Next
    
    Next
    actualRowNumber = actualRowNumber + 2
Next

    End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pointers to help you rather than a complete code answer:

You can use an outer loop over the webElements collection returned by

```
wd.FindElementsByCss("[role=table]")
```

You can then work off the current table within each journey through the loop.

Use a counter instantiated (as 0) before the loop for row number to write out to, which you add to when doing each:

Pseudo code:

```
Dim table As WebElement, actualRowNumber As Long

For Each table in wd.FindElementsByCss("[role=table]")
    RowNum = table....... 'logic based on selecting relative to current table
    ColNum = table.......

    For i = 1 To RowNum
        actualRowNumber = actualRowNumber + i
        '''' loop columns of current row......

    Next
    actualRowNumber = actualRowNumber + number of rows space between tables
Next
```

1. It is also worth noting that there is an inbuilt method for writing out tables: `.AsTable.ToExcel`, or if you already declared table as `Selenium.Table` then just `ToExcel`. You then specify the range to write out to. You would need to determine the last row each time, then add how ever many rows to that to leave a space between tables when writing out all tables in a loop.
2. Selenium isn't needed. The tables are returned in static xmlhttp request so you can avoid the overhead of the browser and still scrape all the tables.

---

EDIT:

Personally, I would avoid browser and just use clipboard to copy paste tables to sheet (as tables are basic and not heavily formatted). Using `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` as the html parser, you can use `querySelectorAll()` method to apply the CSS attribute=value selector to grab the tables. You then loop the returned list of tables.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutTables()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Const ROWS_BETWEEN_TABLES = 3
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.worldathletics.org/competition/calendar-results/results/7147613?day=2", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, clipboard As Object
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, nextRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("[role=table]")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tables")   'need sheet named Tables. Note, this method can give unexpected results if formatting in sheets or values present out of sight in sheet.
    
    With ws.Cells
        .ClearContents
        .ClearFormats
    End With
    
    For i = 0 To tables.length - 1
        clipboard.SetText tables.Item(i).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        lastRow = GetLastRow(ws)
        nextRow = IIf(lastRow < 2, 1, lastRow + ROWS_BETWEEN_TABLES)
        ws.Cells(nextRow, 1).PasteSpecial
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Tables written out"
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    GetLastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False).row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

Without using clipboard and having dates as strings

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutTables()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Const ROWS_BETWEEN_TABLES = 3
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.worldathletics.org/competition/calendar-results/results/7147613?day=2", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, clipboard As Object
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, nextRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("[role=table]")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tables")   'need sheet named Tables. Note, this method can give unexpected results if formatting in sheets or values present out of sight in sheet.
    
    With ws.Cells
        .ClearContents
        .ClearFormats
    End With
    
    For i = 0 To tables.length - 1
        
        Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
        
        Set table = tables.Item(i)
        lastRow = GetLastRow(ws)
        nextRow = IIf(lastRow < 2, 1, lastRow + ROWS_BETWEEN_TABLES)
        WriteOutTable ws, table, nextRow
        
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Tables written out"
End Sub

Public Sub WriteOutTable(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, ByVal nextRow As Long)

    Dim row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow, col As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell, r As Long, c As Long

    With ws

        For Each row In table.Rows
            c = 1
            For Each col In row.Cells
                .Cells(r + nextRow, c) = IIf(c = 3, "'" & col.innerText, col.innerText)
                c = c + 1
            Next
            r = r + 1
        Next

    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    GetLastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False).row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr. I have edited the code according to your points (I think...) but I am getting a runtime error at loop For j when sending data to the sheet. How could implement .astable.toexcel there?

Comment: What is the runtime error and on which line exactly? I have also provided a simpler method you might find helpful.

Comment: I get the error "Index out of array bounds" at this line:             Range("a2").Offset(i - 1, j - 1) = table.FindElementsByTag("tr")(i).FindElementsByTag("td")(j).Text

Comment: Regarding the example you wrote, it seems to work but after importing several tables (not always the same number of them) I get the 1004 error "Application-defined or Object-defined error".

Comment: You would need to debug the values of i and j to work out which is to blame. For my example, how are you using this that you generate this error? Is it by running the same code against the same url multiple times in succession? After `.send`, on a new line, put `Msgbox .status` to check http response status for any obvious request fails.

Comment: Regarding your code, I inserted what you told me and the http response status is 200. Anyway, it works perfectly. I think I had other macros open when I got those errors. Just a question. Is there some way I could import data without any format? Just text as appears at website. Especially at Birth Date and Mark fields.

Comment: it works with Birth Date but it seems Mark gets some format. You can see at the link what the macro gives me (left) and what I get from a copy 6 pastr from the website (right). https://gyazo.com/a60a4b6a9b092f102fef73b3fe22e894

Comment: That will be Excel formatting not the code. You could prepend ' as I did with Birth Date to preserve as on page but with leading '. You would then use IIF(c = 3 OR c = ...., .. , ... ) to apply to the relevant column numbers